# Transform svg icons in js

Tags: javascript, svg, gulp

I have a library of SVG icons (files) that I need to put in js variables that can then be imported after a build in other parts of the application. This process will be performed by a gulp script that must convert the svgs. The scenario can be resumed with the following example:

Folders:

```
dist/
 |_icons/
src/
 |_svgs/
gulpfile.js
```

```html
<!-- svgs/MyIcon.svg -->
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="....very long path..." fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

```js
gulp.task('build-icons', function() {
    return gulp.src(`src/svgs/*.svg`)
        .pipe(gulpRename((path) => {
            //rename svg, not important for the scope
        }))
        .pipe(gulpChange(function(content, done) {
            //here I want to "convert" the svg to a JS file
            //I'm open to ideas for this part, either use document.create, 
            //or whatever allows me to obtain a SVG that I can then import
            //and inject using JQuery
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/icons/'));
});
```

Comment: The question is: what do you want the JS file to be? Just a string? A DOMElement? If the first, return `export const ${name} = "${string}"`, if the second you could do `export const ${name} = new DOMParse().parseFromString( string, 'image/svg+xml' ).querySelector( 'svg' )`?

Comment: I updated the comment. I must obtain something that I can then import into another module that uses JQuery to inject elements in a web page

Comment: So it's just a string that you need to export. When you inject using jQuery (consider stepping away from jQuery as JS can do most of that out of the box these days), its probably parsed as a string. So export a file with `export const ${nameOfSVGFile} = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,${encodeURIComponent(content)}";`